# MS CRM 2016 Online custom SSRS Report with Sub report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a custom `SSRS FetchXml` based *report 'A'* for a MS CRM 2016 online instance.The report has RowGroups as well as ColumnGroups as shown below -

[image]

I am using a tablix here and for the expression in the header I'm formatting the date field (Target Month) and displaying the month and year. The expression in the data row counts the no of records.

*Expression in the datarow* `=IIF(CountRows()=0 OR IsNothing(CountRows()),0, CountRows())`

When the report is executed, it displays the data in the following way -

[image]

Now, I have been asked to create a `sub report / drill-down` report for this where I would need to show the record details from the corresponding horizontal Row Group *Total* counts (highlighted in the above screenshot). I found out that I would need to create another *report 'B'* with the details of the records and then would need to toggle on the RowGroup `GrpByLOB_IndividualBranches`.

So I created a new *report 'B'* as shown below with 3 parameters *BranchName*, *Line* and *TargetMonth* to this report.-

[image]

Added a new *subreport* to my existing main *report 'A'*.

From the subreport I referenced *report 'B'* to use it as a sub report to my main *report 'A'* and created the 3 parameters as mentioned above.

Now this is where I am facing the issue. I need to show the subreport for each of the correponding `Line` items and because of the presence of the ColumnGroup `GroupByTargetMonth` I am not sure how and where to place the subreport such that the ColumnGroup does not influence the data on the subreport.

How can I show the record details inside the tablix with this subreport?

I would need to show the record details below each `Line` item as is shown with the arrow marks in the attached screen below -

[image]

How can I achieve this?